# Maximum memory usage reached (4294967296), cannot allocate chunk of 1048576

Tags: cassandra

I getting errors on Cassandra 3.11.4 debug.log as below.

what could be the reason ? how to avoid these errors.??

I can see partition size is 1.9 MB. Heap size 16GB.

===============

```
free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          64264       23748        3279         619       37236       33190
Swap:             0           0           0
```

=======================

```
lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                16
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-15
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             16
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 85
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6148 CPU @ 2.40GHz
Stepping:              4
CPU MHz:               2394.482
BogoMIPS:              4788.96
Virtualization:        VT-x
Hypervisor vendor:     KVM
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              1024K
L3 cache:              28160K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-15
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon rep_good nopl eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq vmx ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx avx512f rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb avx512cd xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 arat
nodetool tablestats test_data.local_data -H
Total number of tables: 37
----------------
Keyspace : test_data
        Read Count: 0
        Read Latency: NaN ms
        Write Count: 48776898
        Write Latency: 1.534334614042082 ms
        Pending Flushes: 2
                Table: local_data
                SSTable count: 84
                Space used (live): 115.53 GiB
                Space used (total): 115.53 GiB
                Space used by snapshots (total): 165.45 KiB
                Off heap memory used (total): 216.71 MiB
                SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.5440445152549487
                Number of partitions (estimate): 139647
                Memtable cell count: 1495900
                Memtable data size: 167.87 MiB
                Memtable off heap memory used: 174.38 MiB
                Memtable switch count: 2016
                Local read count: 0
                Local read latency: NaN ms
                Local write count: 48777246
                Local write latency: 1.580 ms
                Pending flushes: 2
                Percent repaired: 0.0
                Bloom filter false positives: 0
                Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
                Bloom filter space used: 287.65 KiB
                Bloom filter off heap memory used: 431.88 KiB
                Index summary off heap memory used: 160.4 KiB
                Compression metadata off heap memory used: 41.75 MiB
                Compacted partition minimum bytes: 3974
                Compacted partition maximum bytes: 1955666
                Compacted partition mean bytes: 1109275
                Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): NaN
                Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 0
                Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): NaN
                Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 0
                Dropped Mutations: 6 bytes
```

========================================

```
nodetool tablehistograms test_data local_data
test_data/local_data histograms
Percentile  SSTables     Write Latency      Read Latency    Partition Size        Cell Count
                              (micros)          (micros)           (bytes)
50%             0.00            315.85              0.00           1358102             61214
75%             0.00            943.13              0.00           1955666            152321
95%             0.00           2816.16              0.00           1955666            152321
98%             0.00           8409.01              0.00           1955666            152321
99%             0.00          36157.19              0.00           1955666            152321
Min             0.00             73.46              0.00              3974               373
Max             0.00         557074.61              0.00           1955666            152321
```

====================================

```
nodetool info
ID                     : 2985f5ef-5b84-4654-91f6-dc459741e9fc
Gossip active          : true
Thrift active          : false
Native Transport active: true
Load                   : 117.25 GiB
Generation No          : 1576230314
Uptime (seconds)       : 15745
Heap Memory (MB)       : 8040.00 / 16384.00
Off Heap Memory (MB)   : 287.19
Data Center            : dc1
Rack                   : rack1
Exceptions             : 0
Key Cache              : entries 36568, size 66.79 MiB, capacity 100 MiB, 26555 hits, 63045 requests, 0.421 recent hit rate, 14400 save period in seconds
Row Cache              : entries 0, size 0 bytes, capacity 0 bytes, 0 hits, 0 requests, NaN recent hit rate, 0 save period in seconds
Counter Cache          : entries 0, size 0 bytes, capacity 50 MiB, 0 hits, 0 requests, NaN recent hit rate, 7200 save period in seconds
Chunk Cache            : entries 65024, size 3.97 GiB, capacity 3.97 GiB, 12839660 misses, 15296535 requests, 0.161 recent hit rate, 468.900 microseconds miss latency
Percent Repaired       : 1.8637552068836277E-7%
Token                  : (invoke with -T/--tokens to see all 256 tokens)
```

==================================

```
nodetool netstats
Mode: NORMAL
Not sending any streams.
Read Repair Statistics:
Attempted: 0
Mismatch (Blocking): 0
Mismatch (Background): 0
Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed   Dropped
Large messages                  n/a         2              0         2
Small messages                  n/a         0       66196004         4
Gossip messages                 n/a         0          54691        30
```

=========================

```
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:8] 2019-12-13 17:49:53,408 NoSpamLogger.java:91 - Maximum memory usage reached (4294967296), cannot allocate chunk of 1048576
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:9] 2019-12-13 18:04:55,683 NoSpamLogger.java:91 - Maximum memory usage reached (4294967296), cannot allocate chunk of 1048576
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:6] 2019-12-13 18:21:39,420 NoSpamLogger.java:91 - Maximum memory usage reached (4294967296), cannot allocate chunk of 1048576
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:8] 2019-12-13 18:36:45,011 NoSpamLogger.java:91 - Maximum memory usage reached (4294967296), cannot allocate chunk of 1048576
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:9] 2019-12-13 18:51:53,479 NoSpamLogger.java:91 - Maximum memory usage reached (4294967296), cannot allocate chunk of 1048576
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:7] 2019-12-13 19:06:55,898 NoSpamLogger.java:91 - Maximum memory usage reached (4294967296), cannot allocate chunk of 1048576
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer with the output of the `free` command?

Comment: free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          64264       23748        3279         619       37236       33190
Swap:             0           0           0

=============================

Comment: Hello sateesh, and welcome to SO. Try to edit your question adding more details, instead of putting them in comments: these are not meant for that purpose, and generally it is not expected to find useful info in them.

Answer (score 1):

The chunk cache was something that is somewhat new. It is controlled by the file_cache_size_in_mb setting in the cassandra.yaml. If you run a "nodetool info" command you'll see the size of the chunk cache. I believe the default is (MemTotal - Heap)/2. It's used to cache table chunks when reading, helping optimize read performance. Things move in and out of the chunk cache continuously as things are read. If there is more being read into it faster than going out, it "fills up", and thus you get the message. You could increase the chunk cache or simply ignore the message.

FYI,
If you're looking for a good article on how reads/writes work (with chunks), see this article:

https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2018/08/08/compression_performance.html

-Jim

Comment: Thanks Jim, how to increase chunk cache ?

Comment: Increase this parameter in the cassandra.yaml file: file_cache_size_in_mb